# Javascript Parsing of Serialized Groovy Map to JS literal Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grails, spring-websocket

## String rendered from Server :

```
""['opened':[111, 211, 311, 411, 1013, 1113, 1219], 'closed':[]]""
```

After Applying `JSON.parse` , we get :

```
"['opened':[111, 211, 311, 411, 1113, 1219], 'closed':[]]"
  //means  : omit the double `"` , from `""something""` to `"something"`
```

However, the expected result is a Literal object   :

i.e :

```
   {'opener': [111, 211, 311, 411, 1113, 1219], 'closed':[] }
```

How to reach this result ? i mean a Javascript literal object from serialized Groovy Map

---

## More Details : Server Side :

```
@MessageMapping("/project")
@SendTo("/topic/project")
protected String project(String parameter) {
      def map = ['opened':[111, 211, 311, 411, 1013, 1113, 1219], 'closed':[]]
     return map.inspect()
     
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be valid JSON in the first place. I can't parse the server string using the console. `Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 2):

You could make your life a lot simpler if you return the Groovy map as JSON instead of a String, e.g.

```
def myAction() {
  def map = ['opened':[111, 211, 311, 411, 1013, 1113, 1219], 'closed':[]]
  def json = map as JSON
  [result: json, contentType: 'application/json']
}
```

Then you can read as a JavaScript object on the client-side with something like

```
var someObject = ${result};
```

If your action is being called via AJAX you should use the following action instead:

```
def myAction() {
  def map = ['opened':[111, 211, 311, 411, 1013, 1113, 1219], 'closed':[]]
  render map as JSON
}
```

Comment: the problem that we use Spring-websocket not the built-in action. See Update .